# selenium python - unable to find a hidden element in table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code and I'm trying to get player statistics from this MLB website (http://www.espn.com/mlb/boxscore?gameId=370403101):

```
from selenium import webdriver


link = 'http://www.espn.com/mlb/boxscore?gameId=370403101'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/PATH/chromedriver')
driver.get(link)

player_name_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gamepackage-box-score"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[1]/a/span').text
ab_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gamepackage-box-score"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[3]').text
run_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gamepackage-box-score"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[4]').text
hit_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gamepackage-box-score"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[5]').text
rbi_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gamepackage-box-score"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[6]').text
bb_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gamepackage-box-score"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[7]').text
strk_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gamepackage-box-score"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[8]').text
p_val_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gamepackage-box-score"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[9]').text
avg_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gamepackage-box-score"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[10]').text
obp_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gamepackage-box-score"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[11]').text
slg_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gamepackage-box-score"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/td[12]').text

driver.close()

val_list_away = [player_name_away, ab_away, run_away, hit_away, rbi_away, bb_away, strk_away,
                 p_val_away, avg_away, obp_away, slg_away]

print(val_list_away)
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following list back:

```
['D. Travis', '6', '0', '2', '0', '0', '', '', '.333', '', '']
```

The values for `strk_away`, `p_val_away`, `obp_away`, and `slg_away` are missing, however, as can be seen in the image below, the html code should be accessible to selenium. Can anyone please help? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `selenium` to load the page, and then `BeautifulSoup` to find the player attributes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import collections
player = collections.namedtuple('player', ['name', 'position', 'stats'])
d = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jamespetullo/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get('http://www.espn.com/mlb/boxscore?gameId=370403101')
player_names = iter([b.text for b in soup(d.page_source, 'lxml').find_all('td', {'class':'name'})])
full_stats = [i.text for i in h.find_all('td', {'class':re.compile('batting-stats')})]
final_results = {next(player_names):full_stats[i:i+11] for i in range(0, len(full_stats), 11)}
final_players = [player(*[re.sub('[A-Z\d\-\s\(\),]+$', '', a), (lambda x:'N/A' if not x else x[0])(re.findall('[A-Z\d\-\s\(\),]+$', a)), b]) for a, b in final_results.items()]
```

Output:

```
[player(name=u'K. Morales', position=u'DH', stats=[u'0-4', u'4', u'0', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'1', u'21', u'.000', u'.200', u'.000']), player(name=u'C. Gentry', position=u'PR-RF', stats=[u'0-1', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'2', u'.000', u'.000', u'.000']), player(name=u'D. Travis', position=u'2B', stats=[u'2-6', u'6', u'0', u'2', u'0', u'0', u'2', u'16', u'.333', u'.333', u'.333']), player(name=u'J. Smith', position='N/A', stats=[u'1-4', u'4', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'19', u'.250', u'.400', u'.500']), player(name=u'a - D. Barney', position=u'PH-LF', stats=[u'0-1', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'1', u'4', u'.000', u'.000', u'.000']), player(name=u'M. Machado', position=u'3B', stats=[u'0-4', u'4', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'1', u'11', u'.000', u'.000', u'.000']), player(name=u'J. Bautista', position=u'RF', stats=[u'0-5', u'5', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'21', u'.000', u'.167', u'.000']), player(name=u'J. Donaldson', position=u'3B', stats=[u'3-5', u'5', u'0', u'3', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'23', u'.600', u'.667', u'.600']), player(name=u'J.P. Howell', position='N/A', stats=[u'0-0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'.000', u'.000', u'.000']), player(name=u'H. Kim', position=u'LF', stats=[u'0-0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'.000', u'.000', u'.000']), player(name=u'M. Trumbo', position=u'DH', stats=[u'1-4', u'4', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'1', u'14', u'.250', u'.250', u'.500']), player(name=u'J. Rickard', position=u'LF', stats=[u'1-4', u'4', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'19', u'.250', u'.400', u'.500']), player(name=u'S. Pearce', position=u'1B-LF', stats=[u'3-5', u'5', u'1', u'3', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'8', u'.600', u'.600', u'.600']), player(name=u'T. Tulowitzki', position=u'SS', stats=[u'0-5', u'5', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'23', u'.000', u'.000', u'.000']), player(name=u'C. Davis', position=u'1B', stats=[u'9-39', u'39', u'3', u'9', u'3', u'2', u'5', u'152', u'', u'', u'']), player(name=u'R. Martin', position=u'C', stats=[u'0-3', u'3', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'2', u'2', u'26', u'.000', u'.400', u'.000']), player(name=u'b - J. Smoak', position=u'PH-1B', stats=[u'0-1', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'1', u'5', u'.000', u'.000', u'.000']), player(name=u'', position=u'TEAM', stats=[u'2-5', u'5', u'1', u'2', u'2', u'0', u'0', u'13', u'.400', u'.400', u'1.200']), player(name=u'J. Biagini', position='N/A', stats=[u'1-1', u'1', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'5', u'1.000', u'1.000', u'1.000']), player(name=u'J.J. Hardy', position=u'SS', stats=[u'1-5', u'5', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'2', u'22', u'.200', u'.200', u'.200']), player(name=u'E. Carrera', position=u'LF', stats=[u'2-3', u'3', u'0', u'2', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'12', u'.667', u'.667', u'1.000']), player(name=u'J. Schoop', position=u'2B', stats=[u'1-4', u'4', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'23', u'.250', u'.400', u'.250']), player(name=u'A. Jones', position=u'CF', stats=[u'0-4', u'4', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'13', u'.000', u'.000', u'.000']), player(name=u'S. Smith', position=u'RF', stats=[u'2-4', u'4', u'0', u'2', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'15', u'.500', u'.500', u'.750']), player(name=u'A. Loup', position='N/A', stats=[u'1-4', u'4', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'23', u'.250', u'.400', u'.250']), player(name=u'M. Estrada', position='N/A', stats=[u'1-4', u'4', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'1', u'14', u'.250', u'.250', u'.500']), player(name=u'K. Pillar', position=u'CF', stats=[u'1-4', u'4', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'20', u'.250', u'.400', u'.250']), player(name=u'W. Castillo', position=u'C', stats=[u'1-1', u'1', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'5', u'1.000', u'1.000', u'1.000']), player(name=u'J. Grilli', position=u' (L, 0-1)', stats=[u'1-5', u'5', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'2', u'22', u'.200', u'.200', u'.200']), player(name=u'a - T. Mancini', position=u'PH', stats=[u'0-3', u'3', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'15', u'.000', u'.000', u'.000'])]
```

The result also yields the full stats for `"D. Travis"`:

```
[u'2-6', u'6', u'0', u'2', u'0', u'0', u'2', u'16', u'.333', u'.333', u'.333']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that moving forward you may need to extract the statistics of several players from several tables I have modified your program as follows :

- Code Block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  link = 'http://www.espn.com/mlb/boxscore?gameId=370403101'
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www.google.com")
  driver.get(link)
  item_name_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='boxscore-2017__team-name' and contains(.,'Blue Jays Hitting')]//following::table[1]/thead//th[@class='name']").text
  player_name_away = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='boxscore-2017__team-name' and contains(.,'Blue Jays Hitting')]//following::table[1]/tbody//td//span").text
  print("%s : %s" %(item_name_away, player_name_away)) 
  attributes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='boxscore-2017__team-name' and contains(.,'Blue Jays Hitting')]//following::table[1]/thead//th[starts-with(@class,'batting-stats-')]")
  values = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='boxscore-2017__team-name' and contains(.,'Blue Jays Hitting')]//following::table[1]/tbody[@class='athletes' and @data-athlete-id='32938']//tr[@class='baseball-lineup__player-row']/td[starts-with(@class,'batting-stats-')]")
  for attribute, value in zip(attributes, values):
      print(attribute.text, value.text)
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
  HITTERS : D. Travis

  AB 6
  R 0
  H 2
  RBI 0
  BB 0
  K 2

  AVG .333
  OBP .333
  SLG .333
  ```

**Note** : Neither the column header **P** nor it's value **16** is represented in the *UI* so *Selenium* would be able to extract it.